# How to run quartz job for every working days of month

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

I need to run a job which needs to run first working day of each month, also i need to remove the holidays and get the first working day for each month.

FE : first of may is holiday, so that job needs to run on second day of may.

for the other jobs i use below code.

```
 public CronTriggerFactoryBean testBean() {
    CronTriggerFactoryBean bean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    bean.setJobDetail(test().getObject());
    bean.setName("test");
    bean.setGroup("test");
    bean.setCronExpression("0 45 3 ? * *");
    return bean;
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I would maybe write a bash script to schedule this task

Comment: Every country has own holidays, so first of all, it depends on which country do you want use in your application.

Comment: @Dred days are not important, it could change.

Comment: even in one given country, you have differences between region... 1st may is holiday in Jura (CH), not in Geneva (CH).

Comment: lets assume that we use USA holidays, do we have a solution for the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CRON  doesn't and probably will never support any mechanism recognizing whether the holiday at the current or given location is. The holidays are inconsistent among countries and sometimes even among provinces (usually geographically large countries).

This feature would be very complicated for such simple-to-use designated expressions such as CRON is.

The only possible thing you can do to trigger every day from Monday to Friday (`2-6`) regardless of the holidays and perform some additional holiday check within the given job. In case the `2-6` or `MON-FRI` expression doesn't work, use `2,3,4,5,6`.

```
bean.setCronExpression("0 45 3 ? * 2-6"); 
// At 03:45:00am, every day between Monday and Friday, every month
```

**Disclaimer**: CRON's week starts from Sunday (`1`).

Answer (score 2):

Realizing that requirement via cron expression(s) would probably too complicated.
I would go with a cron expression that runs Monday to Friday, e. g.

`0 3 45 * * MON-FRI`

and check if the current day is a holiday inside the job by verifying against a list of dates.